# Размер картинки в кнопке ImageButton

Tags: android

Есть кнопка ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageButton"
  android:layout_width="24dp"
  android:layout_height="24dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:onClick="onClickMenu"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_point_white" />
```

В нее загружаю картинку размером 24dp на 24dp.
Я увеличиваю ширину кнопки до 48dp, высота остается такой же, картинка при этом тоже растягивается.

Как сделать чтобы размер картинке в кнопе всегда оставался без изменений?

Вот исходное изображение картинки в кнопке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил

```
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Получил вот такое изображение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` попробуйте. И добавьте картинки с примером отображения.

Comment: Только сейчас заметил что у вас там похоже не картинка, а векторный рисунок, удаляйте `scaleType` . Покажите xml `ic_baseline_point_white`. У меня никаких проблем с отображением в кнопке векторных рисунков не наблюдается. Из ваших картинок я не понял в чем конкретно у вас проблема.

Comment: да, там действительно вектор. Проблема в том что точки отображаются корректно только если размер кнопки 24 на 24, а как только я меняю размер кнопки изображение начинает плыть